# Type inference failed. Please try to specify type arguments explicitly

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin

Please help, I'm getting error when I'm trying to build android app from an old source code with latest build tools.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 999) {

        val uri = data!!.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI) as Uri
        currentToneUri = uri.toString()
        sharedPref.edit().putString(AppUtils.NOTIFICATION_TONE_URI_KEY, currentToneUri).apply()
        val ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mCtx, uri)
        etRingtone.editText!!.setText(ringtone.getTitle(mCtx))

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you specify the line of the error (and more details if available)?

Comment: val uri = data!!.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI) as Uri

Comment: Try `getParcelableExtra<Uri>(`. Just guessing, I’m on my phone.